# How to make toggle button transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

How to make toggle button transparent on hovering?

```
 header .navbar-toggle {
    border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
header .navbar-header button {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I use bootstrap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<style>
  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle,
  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus,
  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
</style>


<div class=container>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this code. It's still not transparent as I wanted.

Comment: How transparent you want?

Comment: I want to red rid of the gray background when I hover on the button.

Comment: You want Red color on hover?

Comment: I want no color

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Without !important.
I got another question. How to change the color of (☰) on hovering?

Comment: Use selector `navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar`, and if this answer worked for you, vote up and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use transparent property

```
header .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: header .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
I tried it with !important. Now it works.